# Change - Google cloud storage, transfer Service - Change Object ownership

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-iam

I've moved some files across from S3 to GCS but the objects are now owned by the transfer service, when I try to update the ACL using GSUTIL it says I am not the owner. It seems because the transfer service created the objects it owns them. Is there a way to mimic the transfer service (or log in via it's service account) in order to change the ownership to myself.

Service account name:

**project-XXXXXXXXX@storage-transfer-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com**

I'm trying to run this command:

`gsutil acl ch -u allUsers:R gs://[BUCKETNAME]/`

When doing so I get this error:

> Please ensure you have OWNER-role access to this resource

Please help.

Comment: Just a quick question, your bucket Access control has been set as [Uniform](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access#overview)? If so, open your bucket edit page and change Access control to Fine-grained.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have privileges/permission to run that command. Please make sure that your account have one the following roles in IAM to execute the command or to make a changes on your bucket:

- roles/owner
- roles/editor
- roles/storage.admin

Comment: I have all of those and the legacy ones, it's really strange, I can change them manally in the UI but from gsutil it says I don't own them. There's terrabytes of data so I can't do this manually.

Comment: Make sure that you are on the correct project `gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]` and try to re login or authenticate by doing the command `gcloud auth login`.